# Why Won't my PHP Form Code work Correctly?

Tags: php, forms, if-statement

I am trying to create a form in php with an else/if statement that asks the user for their name and age. It greets them with a welcome message and their name, and then if their age is 16 or over, the statement echos "You are old enough to volunteer for our program." If the user is under the age of 16, the statement will echo "Sorry, try again when you are older. Here is my code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="postName">
Age: <input type="text" name="age"><br /><br />
<input type="submit">
</form>
<br />

Hello, 

<?php

echo $_POST['postName'];

?>

!
<br>


<?php

$age = 'age';

if ($age>=16)
{

    echo $_POST["you are old enough to volunteer for our program!"];
}

else {
    echo $_POST["Sorry, try again when you're 16 or older."];
}

?>
```

The input form is shown correctly, but "Sorry, try again when you're 16 or older" already appears when I open the web page and when I put my name and age in there, the welcome message with the users name works correctly, but absolutely nothing happens with the age statement. It still just says "try again when you're older" no matter what age I put in. HELP :(

Comment: Change this

$age = "age"; to  $age=$_POST['age'];

Comment: Side note, I think you just want to do `echo "You are old enough to volunteer for our program!";` I doubt your key name is *"you are old enough to volunteer for our program!"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters you need to use `$_POST["age"]` and not `age`. Also you should check if you are using get or post using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`.

```
If ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
   // HandleForm
} else {
   // showForm
}
```

Comment: what is 'handleform' and 'showform'? I'm very new to php

Comment: Your code that shows the form and handles the form.

For your example below the <br /> is handleform and above is show form.

Comment: so then where would I put the "if ($age>=16) if there is already an IF statement for the If ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") ?

Comment: Inside the if statement. Such as like this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11839302/4639242

Comment: Do i do the same for GET? Like this?

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET") {

Comment: Nope the get is handled in the else.